# Using #SNMP Set command to set the value of an object identifier to 1 or 0

Tags: c#, snmp, sharp-snmp

I am trying to use #SNMP to set the value of an object identifier to 1 or 0.

Here is an example of the code that I am using:

```
var result = Messenger.Set(VersionCode.V1,new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPAddress), SNMPPortNo),new OctetString("public"),new List<Variable>{new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.1.6.3.1.2.1"),new OctetString("1"))}, 60000);
```

I keep getting an exception with a message "error in response"

Comment: You will need to find a good enough SNMP book to study the basics. That OID is of type `INTEGER`, so you cannot assign OCTET STRING data to it. Nothing is wrong on #SNMP Library side, but just you misunderstood the concepts.

Comment: Lex, thanks for your comment. I knew that nothing is wrong with #SNMP library. Which structure do I need to use to set the object ID, I am trying to change, to 1 or 0.